# Form never gets submitted in symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

i am a newbee in symfony2.

I am working on a searching functionality and here is my code in my indexAction:

```
  /**
 * @Route("/admin/users/", name="userspage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{

    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
    $users = $repo->getUsers();

    //create
    $form = $this->createForm(new SearchType());

    if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isSubmitted()) {
        if($form->isValid()){
            return new Response("Valid");
        } else {
            return new Response("Not Valid");
        }    
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:User:index.html.twig', array(
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
        'active_nav' => 'users',
        'users' => $users,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Here is my FormType:

```
class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('term', 'text' , array('attr'=> array('placeholder'=>
        'Enter name to search', 'class' => 'form-control'),
        'label' => 'Search: '
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_search';
    }
}
```

Here is how i render the form:

```
   <div class="row row-padding no-gutter">
        <form action="{{ path('userspage') }}" method="GET">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                {{ form_label(form.term) }}
            </div>   
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.term) }}
            </div> 
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
            </div> 
            {{ form_rest(form) }}
        </form>
    </div>
```

My problem is, the form never gets valid and never gets submitted. Why is that so?

Thanks.

Comment: Your form is method="GET" right :? Why don't you follow the documentations .. [Symfony2 Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-method-of-a-form)

Comment: Does the submit happen in the browser? Have a look at the network tab in your browsers debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of a form is POST by default. You can use `->setMethod('GET')` or add `method => 'GET'` to the options to make your form use the GET method.

It's also advised to use `{{ form_start(form) }}` and `{{ form_end(form) }}` instead of hardcoded html tags, since this will make sure your method is alright.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-method-of-a-form for more information.